# CouchDB API query with ?limit=0 returns one row - bug or feature?

Tags: api, couchdb, api-design

I use CouchDB 1.5.0 and noticed a strange thing:

When I query some API action, for example:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5984/mydb/_changes?limit=1"
```

I get the same result with `limit=1` and with `limit=0` and with `limit=-55`. In all cases is a one row from the start of list.

Although, PostgreSQL returns:

- Zero rows when `LIMIT 0`
- Message `ERROR:  LIMIT must not be negative` when `LIMIT -55`

My question is mainly concerned with the API design. I would like to know your opinions.

It's a flaw or maybe it's good/acceptable practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the `_changes` api is designed. If you do not specify the type of feed i.e long-poll, continuous etc the default is to return a list of all the changes in a single results array.

If you want a row by row result of the changes in the database specify the type of feed in the url like so

`curl -X GET "http://localhost:5984/mydb/_changes?feed=continuous"`

Another point to note that in the _changes api using 0 has the same effect as using 1 in limit parameter.